# How to play audio from a server using url in kivy

Tags: python, audio, kivy

I am new to kivy framework.

**What I am trying to do**

I am making a simple audio player using kivy.

*When I tried to play local audio it worked properly*.

**But** when I tried to play audio using a url it is not working

**My code is**

```
import kivy
import logging as l
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

url='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vVvyOrl76PJcLG2xmxrx9eSDOTRxrTli/view?usp=drivesdk'

class music(App):
    sound=SoundLoader.load(url)
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="music playing")
    if sound:
        sound.play()
        l.info('\nplaying')
    else:
        l.info('\nnot playing')
        
    
music().run()
```

The following warning is arising

```
[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vVvyOrl76PJcLG2xmxrx9eSDOTRxrTli/view?usp=drivesdk>
```

**The complete logging details are**

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/@tsmile/projects/sounds/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-03-12_11.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.3 (default, May 27 2020, 02:08:17) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vVvyOrl76PJcLG2xmxrx9eSDOTRxrTli/view?usp=drivesdk>
[INFO   ] 
not playing
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r20p0-01rel0.5a1b26bb5d6f760a7fe004c7d2efd431'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G72 MP3'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
```

I use aarch64

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: not at all but gradually I learnt it' not the correct way of doing it